# JS Design Patterns - Interface to perform different tasks

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

I have different methods in my app to fetch users:

```
1. Fetch international users
2. Fetch users from same region
3. Fetch users from same city
```

Currently, I have implemented 1 method for each one:

```
 const fetchIntenationalUsers = async (limit = 10) => {
   const result = await db.collection("users").limit(limit).get();
   ...
   return parseUsers(result);
 }

 const fetchSameRegionUsers = async (region, limit = 10) => {
   const result = await db.collection("users").where("region", "==", region).limit(limit).get();
   ...
   return parseUsers(result);
 }

 const fetchSameCityUsers = async (city, limit = 10) => {
   const result = await db.collection("users").where("city", "==", city).limit(limit).get();
   ...
   return parseUsers(result);
 }
```

I have thought to create a generalized method like:

```
const fetchUsers = (queryType = "international", location = {}, limit = 10) => {
   const queries = {
      "international": db.collection("users"),
      "region": db.collection("users").where("region", "==", location.region),
      "city": db.collection("users").where("city", "==", location.city),
   };

   const result = await queries[queryType].limit(limit).get();

   ...

   return parseUsers(result);
}
```

But I am not sure if this is an anti-pattern or a design pattern. Any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it's an antipattern to put them all together in a single "generalised" method, and introduce that `queryType` enum. You'll get more and more query types in the future, and it will create a huge mess in that [god method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). (Also, it has the disadvantages mentioned in @CertainPerformance's answer).

Instead, I recommend to keep the separate functions (that can be called separately), but abstract out the duplicated parts of the code into one abstract helper function:

```
async function fetchUsers(addCondition, limit = 10) {
  const query = addCondition(db.collection("users")).limit(limit);
  const result = await query.get();
  …
  return parseUsers(result);
}

export const fetchInternationalUsers = (limit) => 
  fetchUsers(q => q, limit);

export const fetchSameRegionUsers = (region, limit) =>
  fetchUsers(q => q.where("region", "==", region), limit);

export const fetchSameCityUsers = async (city, limit) =>
  fetchUsers(q => q.where("city", "==", city), limit);
```

Answer (score 1):

The general idea looks fine to me, but there's one issue: with this line:

```
const queries = {
  "international": db.collection("users"),
  "region": db.collection("users").where("region", "==", location.region),
  "city": db.collection("users").where("city", "==", location.city),
};
```

You're calling *all* of those database methods when the object is created, not just the one you need. (You also aren't handling possible errors thrown by the unused methods.)

For a slight tweak, consider functions that return the queries instead. You can also do `db.collection('users')` up front.

```
const users = db.collection("users");
const queries = {
   international: () => users,
   region: () => users.where("region", "==", location.region),
   city: () => users.where("city", "==", location.city),
};
const result = await queries[queryType]().limit(limit).get();
```

Comment: "*You're calling all of those database methods*" - which is fine imo, since these methods only generate queries. The query is only executed when `.get()` is called on it. Sure, it's not as efficient as it could be, and especially the query building might fail if `location.…` is not availble.